# How to split beta coefficients of a linear regression model?

Tags: regression, linear-model

Suppose we have a regression model where y is the dependent variable and the predictor variables are x1, x2, x3 and x4. The corresponding betas obtained from the model are b1,b1,b3 and b4 respectively. Now, I have some extra information regarding the variable x1. The x1 has different categories x11, x12 and x13 such that x1 = x11+x12+x13. The objective is to find which one among x11, x12 and x13 has higher impact in affecting the dependent variable y. But it cannot be included in the main model as the data for x11, x12 and x13 is sparse. So, is there any statistical technique through which I can split the b1 coefficient by asserting some weights to the variables x11, x12 and x13 respectively?

Comment: If x1, x2, and x3 are sparse, and x is the sum of those, then how is x not sparse as well?

Comment: Ok an example would be TV ad spends. I run different ad creatives throughout the year but they are at different times of the year. Therefore the individual columns of each ad creatives is sparse.